# cp command not copying file content?

Tags: cp, file-copy

I'm trying to copy a folder with files from a mounted volume to another mounted volume with a simple `cp` command.

The source folder `Test` only contains one 20MB `.mp4` file.

```shell
cp -v -r -a /media/Online/Online/Projekte/Test /mnt/ArchivServer/Online/Projekte/
```

Everything looks fine, the folder structure looks good in the destination, but the files are there by name **but all have 0 byte in size**. It's actually 0 Byte since it can't be openend. There is also no error message.

[image: (The file has roughly 20MB in the source)]

Fairly new to Linux etc, what am I doing wrong? Unfortunately I can't find anything online about this

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us your operating system (you mentioned Linux in passing, so I am guessing it is some Linux or other, but it is always a good idea to tell us which, and Linux is only one of many operating systems supported here). Then, also show us the _actual_ command you used. What was `(source)` and what was `(destination)`? Was `(source)` a file? A directory? Were its contents regular files? Symlinks? Something else? How large were the files in the `source`?

Comment: Also please mention any error messages that your `cp` command produces.

Comment: Question: does the file *work* afterwards? (I have a hunch that this might be more of a problem with the file manager you use showing the wrong size, but I might be wrong)

Comment: Quite so, @ConstantineA.B: `ls -lR /mnt/ArchivServer/Online/Projekte/Test` will show the reality.

Comment: Jotamam please would you run this (one line) command and put its result (two lines) into your question `ls -ld /media/Online/Online/Projekte/Test/220608_Bloopers_Master.mp4 /mnt/ArchivServer/Online/Projekte/220608_Bloopers_Master.mp4`. If you get `No such file or directory` double-check the paths and file name (you might prefer `ls -ld /media/Online/Online/Projekte/Test/*.mp4 /mnt/ArchivServer/Online/Projekte/*.mp4`)

Comment: Try executing `sync` in the terminal and see if it works :)

Comment: After issuing the `cp` command, do you get back the shell prompt?

Comment: You say that the source directory only has a 20MB file, but later on you speak in plural and empasize that _all_ the files are of 0 byte at the destination. Please clarify.